# Is there a way to scan for surrounding cell towers using sim800L or Sim900

Tags: cell, scanning, sim900, sim800

I'm trying to do an exercise where I run my own GSM location triangulation algorithm from scanning surrounding towers and compare the accuracy with built-in GSM location commands (AT+CLBS and AT+CIPGSMLOC etc.)offered by sim800 and sim 900. The closest thing I've found online is a AT+KCELL command for some other modem which is not a generic way to do it (i.e. standard/official AT Commands like 27.007 etc.).

I know this scanning of neighbouring cell ids is pretty common with android and also many other modems but I was looking for a more 'universal' way to do this using AT commands.

If this is not possible does anyone know of alternatives that could get me more degrees of freedom (e.g. firmware for these modules that can extend functionality to support scanning of cells, changing bands, forcing re-registration with different cells)? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Using different hardware is not an option since I'm studying the capability of these simcomm modules for location.

My last resort if this fails is multiple simcards from different operators, but this is too crude of a work-around in hardware to be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Have had no response on this issue so going to leave breadcrumbs for anyone else who stumbles upon this question. From some additional research, the answer seems to be to use Embedded AT development which is available for sim900 but not sure if it is available for sim800. It could be free or not. Only way to find out is to contact simcomm